# SSE response from Spring app does not reach client side

Tags: java, spring, angular, server-sent-events

Am trying to implement SSE for my application. My client is angular 4 app and I use the EventSourcePolyfill (to make it work for IE as well). My server side is spring and I use spring SseEmitter for the same.

I open a new SSE connection, based on a specific user event on the client side. I can see that the request reaches the server, SSE events are logged and I can see the response is getting created as well. I want to send response as json. I'm basically trying to send data updates, and am creating a json with the updated data. But the SSE never reaches the browser. It goes to the Eventsource.onerror method only. So the browser keeps retrying. *

In Chrome -> Dev tools -> Network tab, I can see the SSE request showing in pending for few seconds, then changes to cancelled.

- I have put the code snippets and error information here.

Angular Code:

```
  let eventSource = new EventSourcePolyfill('v1/sse/getInfiniteMessages', {
  // headers: {
  //   'Accept': 'text/event-stream'
  // }, 
  heartbeatTimeout:180
});

eventSource.onmessage = (eventResponse => {
  console.log("Message from event source is :: " + eventResponse);
  console.log("JSON from event source is :: " + eventResponse.data);

});
eventSource.onopen = (a) => {
  // Do stuff here
  console.log("Eventsource.onopen.. " + JSON.stringify(a));
};
eventSource.onerror = (e) => {
  // Do stuff here
  console.log("Eventsource.onerror.. Exception is:: " + JSON.stringify(e));
  if (e.readyState == eventSource.CLOSED) {
    console.log('event source is closed');
    eventSource.close();
   }
   else {
     console.log("Not a event source closed error");
   }
}
```

Spring (server side)

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getInfiniteMessages")
public SseEmitter getInfiniteMessages() { 
    return iSSEService.getInfiniteMessages();
}
```

Service:

```
public SseEmitter getInfiniteMessages(String chatRefId) {
    logger.info("In SSEService.. getInfiniteMessages method.." );

    boolean stopSSE = false;
    while (!stopSSE) {
        try {
            ResponseVo responseVO = new ResponseVo();
            responseVO = getData();
//              Gson gson = new Gson();
//              String sseMessage = gson.toJson(responseVO);
//              logger.info("sseMessage to send: "  + sseMessage);
//                emitter.send(sseMessage , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            emitter.send(responseVO);

            Thread.sleep(30000);
            //stopSSE = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            emitter.completeWithError(e);
            //return;
        }
    }

    /*for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            emitter.send(i + " - Message", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            emitter.completeWithError(e);
            //return;
        }
    }*/

    return emitter;
}
```

The commented lines of code are few things which I tried but did not work.

**Note**: *In the service code, if I uncomment the for loop (running 100 times), the sse text reaches the browser. But I want to send a json with data updates. I tried creating object as json, and send as text, but it did not help.*

**Error**:

From console.log on onError method :

```
Not a event source closed error
    Eventsource.onerror.. Exception is:: {"type":"error","target":{"listeners":{"data":{}},"url":"/v1/sse/getInfiniteMessages","readyState":0,"withCredentials":false}}
```

Browser error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: No activity within 45000 milliseconds. Reconnecting.
    at eventsource.js:363
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:499)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:488)
    at timer (zone.js:2040)
```

Looking for some help from friends here, to solve my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working with the `SseEmitter` before returning it, it doesn't work like that. Since you don't return the emitter reference to the client until the end, the client does not receive anything.

Correct steps: you have to create an `SseEmitter`, store it in memory, let the controller method return it, and then begin emitting items.

Quick and probably incomplete example below:

```
@Controller
public SseController {
    private final List<SseEmitter> emitters = new ArrayList<>();

    @GetMapping("/listen")
    public SseEmitter getEvents() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        emitters.add(emitter);
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> emitters.remove(emitter));
        return emitter;
    }

    @PostMapping("/notify")
    public void postMessage(String message) {
        for (SseEmitter emitter : emitters) {
            emitter.send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we do a `GET /listen` to subscribe to an event stream, and then we can publish messages with `POST /notify` to push messages to all the listening clients, but you could send messages from other sources, such as a looping thread like in your example.

The key concept is the order: create emitter, store emitter, return emitter, then send to emitter.

Comment: Thanks. As I have mentioned, In the service code, if I uncomment the for loop (running 100 times), the sse text reaches the browser. Can you pls help me understand that? And in your example, clients will call GET /listen, to register for the event stream. Who will call the POST /notify? Or you mean to create some kind of thread, which will send message to all the subscribed clients? Also, is there any specific way, for sending a json response? or can I just use emitter.send(object) and it will be automatically converted as json?

Comment: @csharpnewbie sorry but I wouldn't waste time debugging your code seeing that it's wrong. About my example, you can send messages to the list of emitters in any way you want, in this case I used a `POST /notify` but you could use a scheduled method, a thread, or anything you need. You can also be selective about which emitters you send to (you don't have to push to all of them at once). About sending a JSON response, it should be automatically converted to JSON. See this complete tutorial for a more in-depth explanation: https://golb.hplar.ch/p/Server-Sent-Events-with-Spring

Comment: @ESala I have a similar problem, the response reaches the client only after it returns the sse emitter. SseEmiter->send doesn't send the response back to the client. The required condition would be -> EventSource('startListen') and the response should come each time the server does SseEmiter.send.